# Make Visual Studio understand CamelCase when hitting Ctrl and cursor keys

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

**Is there a way that I can configure Visual Studio 2008 to understand CamelCase?**  Specifically, I'd like to be able to get `Ctrl + right` or `left` cursor to take me to a subsection of a variable or type name.

i.e., if my cursor was at the start of this line:

```cs
LongNamedExampleClass longNamed = new LongNamedExampleClass();
```

and I hit `Ctrl + right`, I'd like to jump to "`Named`" in the class name, rather than the start of the variable name.  If I hit it again, I'd like to go to "`Example`".  I hope that makes sense.

I used this navigational feature in Eclipse quite a lot, and find it difficult to unlearn something so ingrained.

Comment: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html) supports that feature.

Comment: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) does that. I suppose you could write your own addin to do the same.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Thanks to those who suggested Resharper. This gives me another reason to love it even more. Just to be specific about where this lives - JetBrains call it [**CamelHumps**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#CamelHumps) (cute) and you can switch it on using the menu:

> **Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Editor -> Editor Behavior -> Use CamelHumps**

... in older versions of Resharper, it is;

> **Resharper -> Options -> Editor -> Use CamelHumps**

Comment: Is there an option, to select the whole word, even if CameHumps is on? At the moment I have to press right or left several times to select a word. I hope you get me.

Comment: To quickly select the whole word while CamelHumps is on, press the [Extend Selection shortcut key](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Extend_Shrink_Selection.html) twice (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Right` or `Ctrl`+`W`).

Comment: Not only select the whole word but jumping across the whole word too?

Comment: This is the correct solution for ctrl+[arrow]. However, there are two resharper commands - Resharper_TextControlPreviousWord and Resharper_TextControlNextWord so that you can bind different shortcuts to do the same camel case navigation. However, they don't work if the CamelHumps option is off.

Answer (score 141):

### Visual Studio 2022 and above have this by default with the shortcut keys [`Ctrl + Alt + Arrows`] for traversal and [`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Arrows`] for selection, but [`Alt + Delete/Backspace`] for deletion need to have Text Editor shortcuts created for them in **"Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard"** set to the commands `Edit.SubwordDeleteToEnd`/`Edit.SubwordDeleteToStart` respectively.

---

> #### Note for users of `Visual Studio Code`
>
> ##### which is a *different program* from `Visual Studio 2022`
>
> The shortcut keys you need to
> *manually set* are **cursorWordPartLeft** & **cursorWordPartRight** for [`Alt + Arrows`] and **cursorWordPartLeftSelect** &
> **cursorWordPartRightSelect** for [`Alt + Shift + Arrows`], and they can be set from **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**. However, it
> does not include anything for [`Alt + Delete/Backspace`]. For that,
> Olle Westman ported their extension over to Visual Studio Code, which
> you can find under the name **"Subword Navigation" by ow**. Those
> shortcut keys are under the name **subwordNavigation**, and I believe
> they come preset.

---

#### Archived Answer below for earlier versions of Visual Studio.

---

Anyone stumbling across this page after Nov 25, 2008 (who don't want to pay for ReSharper or CodeRush *which no longer has a free version*), the following free Extension adds this functionality: **[Subword Navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlleWestman.SubwordNavigation) by Olle Westman**

(Alternatively, the [VSTricks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeMuncher1.VSTricks) extension includes Sub-word Navigation in its list of nifty features. There is also a different [Subword navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vasama.SubwordNavigation) extension created by Lauri Vasama not to be confused with Olle Westman's which this answer uses.)

The Subword Navigation project page states:

> Look up Subword in keyboard bindings to set things up.

Here's how I set it up in **`Visual Studio 2019`**:

---

1. Navigate to **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard**

---

2. Under **`Use new shortcut in`**, select **Text Editor**

---

3. Under **`Show commands containing`**, type **subword**. This should pop up an autocomplete field with the listed commands below.

---

4. Select one of the following commands you want to set its shortcut keys for. Once selected, follow the rest of the numbered steps. Then come back to **`Step 4`** to set another one.

   > **Note:** When assigning these Subword Navigation commands to these new shortcut keys, preserve any already-existing shortcut-key functionality you want to keep beforehand by setting them to different keys. **It should not conflict with any default-installed shortcut keys.**

   #### Traversal

   - **Edit.NextSubword**

     - Traverses camelcases to the right [**`Alt + Right Arrow`**]
   - **Edit.PreviousSubword**

     - Traverses camelcases to the left [**`Alt + Left Arrow`**]

   #### Selection

   - **Edit.NextSubwordExtend**

     - Selects camelcases to the right [**`Alt + Shift + Right Arrow`**]
   - **Edit.PreviousSubwordExtend**

     - Selects camelcases to the left [**`Alt + Shift + Left Arrow`**]

   #### Deletion

   - **Edit.SubwordDeleteToEnd**

     - Deletes camelcases to the right [**`Alt + Delete`**]
   - **Edit.SubwordDeleteToStart**

     - Deletes camelcases to the left [**`Alt + Backspace`**]

---

5. Under **`Press shortcut keys`**, press **Your Shortcut Keys**

---

6. Click **`Assign`** and overwrite the existing shortcut

Comment: Thanks for the head's-up!  This works great, and is the most open of the presented solutions.

Comment: I meant the year 2015 and beyond. As mentioned later, I used this in VS 2012. I'll clarify in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Particularly excellent answer in providing the setup details. I definitely appreciate the explanation on Next/PreviousExtend

Comment: In 2015, I had to overwrite TextEditor.* commands, rather than Global.* commands. ALT+RIGHT was already bound to something else.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work anymore on visual studio 2019

Comment: @yanyankelevich I just tested it in VS2019 and it works. However, I did notice in the Extensions Manager, there were **two** extensions called "Subword Navigation". You want the one created by Olle Westman. I've updated my answer to specify that and note it works in VS2019.

Comment: I went to install this, and started thinking what I would bind to the keyboard shortcut to. "Hm, `CTRL + ALT + Arrow` probably. Let's see if that's already bound to something. Oh wait, it already does this sub-word navigation". 

I couldn't find any extensions I have installed that mention this, so it might already be there in VS 2022? (Edit: looks like an answer below denotes that this is new and included in VS2022)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022. It does not work! These keys have no effect sadly.

Comment: @Tigerware Looks like VS2022 now allows you to manually set options for rightward and leftward deletion of subwords without requiring an extension. Search for `Edit.SubwordDeleteToEnd` & `Edit.SubwordDeleteToStart` in the Keyboard options, and set "Text Editor" shortcuts for them.

Answer (score 22):

If you have ReSharper installed you can also configure Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts "Alt-Right" and "Alt-Left" for CamelHump, without losing standard Visual Studio behaviour for "ctrl-right" and "ctrl-left".

1. Open the Visual Studio **Options** window from **Tools –> Options**
2. Expand **Environment** and scroll down to **Keyboard**
3. In *Show commands containing* box, type "hump". This will show all commands related to CamelHumps.
   [image: CamelHumps]
4. Map the commands to the key mappings you wish by selecting the command from the list and entering the key mapping in the *Press shortcut keys* textbox, then click **Assign**.

Caveats:

- Assign the mappings for **Text Editor**, not **Global**.
- Make sure the *Use CamelHumps* option from Resharper -> Options -> Editor -> Editor Behaviour is **turned off**.

Details here: http://davidrcook.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/working-with-camel-case-in-visual-studio/

Comment: You just made my day. The perfect solution as camel humps can be such a pin with long identifiers (as anyone who uses Eclipse will attest)

Answer (score 8):

It's not native to Visual Studio, but you can get it for free using [CodeRush Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/). (ReSharper and CodeRush require payment).

Comment: Only the trial is free nowadays

Answer (score 5):

For those using Visual Studio 2022.

Ctrl +Alt + right or left will jump to sub words(camel case navigation).

Comment: Also if you hold shift it will do selection too as you would expect

Comment: Does not work with visual studio professional 2022.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio does not support this behavior.  However, [DevExpres's](http://www.devexpress.com/) CodeRush! product supports navigation like this (using Alt-Left & Alt-Right), along with tons of other features to aid in navigation.  The CodeRush! product is also bundled with their Refactor tool.  They also offer a free CodeRush! & Refactor Express product, though I'm not certain if the Camel Casing navigation is part of the express product.

Answer (score 2):

Add the macro below to the visual studio.

http://visualstudiomacros.blogspot.com/2008/03/getting-ctrl-right-arrow-to-respect.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is looking for this in version ~1.63
The keybinding option is now called "cursorWordPart" and can easyly be set in keyboard shortcuts :)

Answer (score 0):

This extension was created to do that, just like in Eclipse:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.camelcasenavigation

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Visual Studio supports this feature internally, as it seems to be using the normal way Ctrl+Right and Ctrl+Left work in Windows environment. But it's probably possible with some kind of extension or plugin.

Comment: Making a guess about whether or not other people are going to be able to answer the question isn't really an answer to the question.