# Is there a Visual Studio plugin (preferably Resharper) that has camel case selection

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Visual Studio understand CamelCase when hitting ctrl and cursor keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys)

**Exact duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys)**

I have some quite long variable / field names in my code and I'm finding the default behaviour for CTRL+SHIFT+Right-Arrow and CTRL+SHIFT+Left-Arrow to be less productive than if it were to adhere to camel casing. Here's an example.

Say the cursor is before the A in AndAnotherThing.
CTRL+SHIFT+Right-Arrow will select the entire variable while adherance to camel casing would only select And.

Is there any tool or plugin for Visual Studio that can do this?

Edit:

I'd also like similar behaviours for CTRL+Left-Arrow and CTRL+Right-Arrow

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resharper supports it, select *Use [CamelHumps](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#CamelHumps)* in *ReSharper* | *Options* | *Editor* 
and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does what you described.

Comment: According to [Visual Assist's documentation](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-coding-assistance.asp#acro) and my own experience, camel casing only affects the code completion feature, not navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not quite what you're asking for, but Resharper has a very useful (but hard to find out about) feature where it respects camelCase by allowing you to type just the Capital Letters of the name.

For example, if you have this declaration

```
List<int> myList;
```

then when you could type

```
myList.ARO|
```

and the Resharper intellisense will have automagically selected AsReadOnly as the completion.

Works for GotoType and GotoMember as well.