# Visual studio ctrl+arrow setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Don't know why Visual Studio 2012 changed ctrl+arrow (left, right) behavior. For example we have line of code:

```
int anyIntValue;
```

I place text cursor as below (`<c>` - text cursor position):

```
int <c>anyIntValue;
```

And after pressing `ctrl`+`right arrow` got this:

```
int any<c>IntValue;
```

So cursor navigates to the nearest uppercase letter. But I need to return to the default behavior when after `ctrl`+`right arrow` we got:

```
int anyIntValue<c>;
```

May be you know where to find such setting in VS?

Comment: This did not change.  Uninstall the add-in that causes this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I am having the opposite problem. Coming from eclipse, i am comfortable with cursor stopping before UPPER case letter. How can i configure this setting?

Comment: Clearly you are looking for the same addin that Sergey is trying to get rid of.  You should ask him, not me.

Comment: I was really hoping that VS 2019 would have this. I found a duplicate question with more ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Visual Studio understand CamelCase when hitting Ctrl and cursor keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should change the resharper editor options. Uncheck the use CamelHumps checkbox.