# Using CamelHumps without resharper or coderush

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

I've read through the previous threads on ctrl+arrow or ctrl+shift+arrow in visual studio using resharper or coderush.

There was one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190122/860947) where a [macro](http://visualstudiomacros.blogspot.com/2008/03/getting-ctrl-right-arrow-to-respect.html) achieved the same result.
However, VS2013 no longer supports macros.

**Is there an alternative way to support camelhumps in Visual Studio 2013 without relying on resharper or coderush?**

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this question before stumbling over the [VSTricks](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/721ceda0-1b36-415b-9c23-ffcbcc83e76e) extension, which does this (and a couple of other things).

After installing, I had to re-map the hotkeys manually, but it was pretty simple:

[image: VSTricks options]

For all the settings in the list, I mapped to the keystrokes that were previously mapped to the corresponding commands for words (e.g. `Edit.SubWordNext` was mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>, which was previously mapped to `Edit.WordNext`).

The extension works in VS2015 too - and, unlike e.g. ReSharper which also has this feature, it's free :)

Comment: That is great news. I'm currently working with VSCode right now, but when I get to some server side code I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with highlight, "ctrl+shift+arrow", is there a way to make it work?