# Is there a way to enable camel humping through method names in VS Code?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, camelcasing

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys) is for the "big" Visual Studio and Resharper, I'd like to see that feature in VS Code too.

Scrolling through the [shortcut list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings) for VS Code, I couldn't find it but I'm hoping that it's still there but called something less intuitive than *camel*, *hump* or such.

Comment: is this question about moving the caret left and right? Or is it about selection expansion and contraction?

Comment: @starball It's actually **both**. The concept of camel-humping means that there's a way to schootch over to the next capital letter (as opposed to the next word). Whether I have *SHIFT* pressed (or whatever is the "selection" key on ones system) or not shouldn't matter. Unless you're referring to the expansion/contraction of a selection in both directions (to the next scope, however we may define it), then no, that's not what the OP intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this extensions to work https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ow.vscode-subword-navigation

Funny thing is that you need to configure each combination separately:

```
{
    "key": "alt+left",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.cursorSubwordLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+right",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.cursorSubwordRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+left",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.cursorSubwordLeftSelect",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+right",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.cursorSubwordRightSelect",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+backspace",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.deleteSubwordLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+delete",
    "command": "subwordNavigation.deleteSubwordRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: @Swaps you need to apply it to `keybindings.json`. The easiest way to access is just to type `shortcuts` in the command search window.

Comment: This feature is now integrated in the application: no Plugin needed
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51329169/3757110

Answer (score 83):

As of version 1.25 these commands are built in:

[image]

Comment: This is solid, you can rebind them all without the alt key and it's just perfect

Comment: This should be changed to the accepted solution! Thanks.

Comment: Using the Ctrl - Alt - Delete keybinding on Windows won't work.

Comment: Please don't embed URL based images, as often these are blocked by eg. VPN firewalls etc.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reasons your bindings are not set here is the JSON to obtain Cezn's shortcuts.

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordPartRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+right",
    "command": "cursorWordPartRightSelection",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
    "command": "cursorWordPartLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+left",
    "command": "cursorWordPartLeftSelection",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+backspace",
    "command": "deleteWordPartLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+delete",
    "command": "deleteWordPartRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Be careful with the ctrl+alt+delete one since it conflicts with another popular windows shortcut.

Other interesting bindings are:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "explorer.newFile",
    "when": "explorerViewletFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+n",
    "command": "explorer.newFolder",
    "when": "explorerViewletFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

VSCode 1.80 (June 2023) includes (in [VScode Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today) [PR 182571](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/182571)

> ### Add option for smartSelect to ignore subwords
>
> This brings VS Code to parity with other major editors/IDEs (e.g., JetBrains IDEs have the Use "`CamelHumps`" words option).
>
> `editor.smartSelect.selectSubwords`
>
> description: Whether subwords (like '`foo`' in '`fooBar`' or '`foo_bar`') should be selected.

Comment: Is it as in *built in, out of the box*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It is a new setting, directly available (in VSCode Insiders for now)

Comment: Please advise. I must be missing something. I run version 1.80.1 (12th of July) and I don't get that setting when I filter for *hump* nor *camel*. I also added it manually to the JSON file, copying the line you quoted. Still, nothing - no camelization based humping going on. How do you activate it on your system?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten It seems to still have an issue, as [reported here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/182571#issuecomment-1609955972).

Comment: Ah, darn... I've found it finally by searching for *smart* (poorly chosen name, given the camels and humps readily available). But checking it gave nothing of use. So yet, it seems that feature still isn't out there for real. IN-not-HO, it's embarrassing that it still isn't implemented properly. Sort of basic functionality...

Comment: @KonradViltersten this is for selection expansion and contraction- not for moving the caret forward and back. that's why I commented on your question post asking about whether the question is about selection expansion and contraction.

Comment: @starball Thanks for the clarification. I guess it's back to my plugin for humping the camels... Darn... I still can't understand what kind of person decides not to have that option from day 0. Probably someone who's never humped a camel...

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for this: [Camel Case Navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.camelcasenavigation)

[image]