# CamelCase navigation without overriding Ctrl+Left/Right in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

Resharper offers a feature called *CamelHump* navigation which overides <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> navigation from jumping between words to jumping between words in camel case.

Presing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> here (where `|` represents cursor positon)

```
GetUserIDFromTestGeneratedAccount|
```

would move the cursor to here

```
|GetUserIDFromTestGeneratedAccount
```

But I would like a means for another shortcut to move it here

```
GetUserIDFromTestGenerated|Account
```

I would like to reiterate, I want *both* ways to navigate and don't want to override standard Ctrl+Left navigation as with the Resharper option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Visual Studio understand CamelCase when hitting ctrl and cursor keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologise for the duplicate question! It was a hard one to search for given the naming, but it's called *"subword navigation"*.

While the [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys) has some great answers, I was able to find this extension which worked great once you setup the shortcuts: [Subword Navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlleWestman.SubwordNavigation)

[image: Setting up keyboard shortcuts for Subword Navigation]