# What key combination or configuration to use in Visual Studio 2022 to forward delete and backspace delete in camel case mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Certainly this is not a duplicate of [Make Visual Studio understand CamelCase when hitting Ctrl and cursor keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/make-visual-studio-understand-camelcase-when-hitting-ctrl-and-cursor-keys).

In that question there is an answer specifically for VS 2022 indicating CTRL+ALT+(RIGHT|LEFT) allow you to traverse right | left along camel case humps.

But what key combinations would actuate forward delete and back delete in camel case mode within features native to Microsoft Visual Studio 2022?

Is there a Visual Studio configuration to allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> then
<kbd>Delete</kbd>

**Option 2**

1. Option → Environment → Keyboard
2. Search *subword*
3. Assign a shortcut to *Edit.SubwordDeleteToEnd/Start*